# Changing Port number in WordPress blog

Tags: wordpress, port, wampserver

First of all I installed wamp server on port 8081 (Because there was IIS on 80). the word process was installed successfully and blog was running smoothly.
Now I stopped the IIS and set the apache port to 80. But the application is redirecting to port 8081.
(Also I copid the wordpress folder to my live domain, in there also it is redirecting to port 8081.)
In which file, I need to change the port number? 
(I have already changed the port number in httpd.conf.)

Thank You in Advance. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Go to **Dashboard > Settings > General** and check what you have for the options:

- WordPress Address (URL)
- Site Address (URL)

Comment: @ChrisNielsen updates the database, specifically the "options" table

Answer (score 14):

I had an issue where the original port I had specified when I installed WP was changed.  I couldn't log into wp-admin because WP kept redirecting to the old port.  I used phpMyAdmin to edit the `wp_options` table.  Both the **siteurl** and **home** records used the old port.  With phpMyAdmin, you can edit cells directly without having to export/import.  I thought I'd add this as an answer just in case it helps someone else down the road.

Or use a SQL like this:

```
update wp_options SET option_value = 'http://your-domain/wordpress:new-port' where option_id = 1 and option_name = 'siteurl';

update wp_options SET option_value = 'http://your-domain:new-port/wordpress' where option_id = 2 and option_name = 'home';
```

Comment: In the SQL section, why do you setup the URL to be site_root :new-port in the first case and site_root:new_port/wordpress in the second. What directory is wordpress/ in both case?

Answer (score 7):

I found same problem but I'm using xampp.

> **Scenario**
>   I have setup another new server using xampp in a different port (8090), then I
>   transferred the existing WordPress to the new server but it was still keeping
>   redirection to the original port.

**Solutions** Updated the **option_value** in the table **wp_options** in mysql to the new port. Here is an example updated query.

```
UPDATE `wordpress`.`wp_options`
SET
`option_value` = 'http://localhost:8090/wordpress'
WHERE `option_id` = 1 or `option_id` = 2;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to do it quickly you can change the values in the database.  Connect to the [mysql] db for your blog and update the values in the wp_options table.

```
    # mysql -u root -p

    > use [yourWordpressDBName]

    >    UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'http://www.oldurl.com:80','http://www.newurlcom:8080') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';
```

And then connect in your browser- the url is changed!

I had to do this to get a 2nd docker instance of WP working on a different port on the host.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your phpmyadmin and inside your database you will see wp_options open it and edit the port

Answer (score 0):

If none of the answers works consider checking your `.htaccess` file.